# How do I rename a selection of variables using dplyr::rename?

Tags: r, dplyr, rename, tidyverse

Hi: I basically need to recode some likert items in a dataframe to numeric and then rename them. I can do this in base R but would like to know how to do this in tidyverse. My stab is here:

```
library(tidyverse)
var1<-sample(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
var2<-var1
var3<-var1
var4<-rnorm(n=4)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4)
recodes<-c('var1', 'var2', 'var3')

df %>% 
select(recodes) %>% 
#everythig works great to this line
mutate_all(funs(dplyr::recode(., 'a'=1, 'b'=0.5, 'c'=0.25, 'd'=0)))%>%
#This is where I need some help
rename_all(funs(paste('ideol', seq(1,3,1))))
```

Solution:

```
df<-df %>% 
select(recodes) %>% 
#everythig works great to this line
mutate_all(funs(dplyr::recode(., 'a'=1, 'b'=0.5, 'c'=0.25, 'd'=0)))%>%
#This is where I need some help
rename_all(funs(paste('ideol', seq(1,3,1), sep='')))%>%
cbind(., df)
```

Comment: If you add %>% to the end of the mutate_all line, the output is: a data frame with variable names "ideol 1", "ideol 2", "ideol 3". Is this not the desired outcome?

Comment: It looks like you just forgot a pipe as @LucyMLi mentioned.

Comment: Of course. I'm so sloppy. Sorry.

Comment: Fixed, but how do I store those variables with the changed names in the original data frame? Or add them to the original data frame?

Comment: This worked as a final line for me. Sorry for cluttering this space
`cbind(., df)`

Comment: @LucyMLi, could you possible post your comment as an answer? This way we can get this question closed. Thanks.

Comment: @EricFail Done :)

Comment: @LucyMLi, you got my votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting comment as answer:

If you add `%>%` to the end of the mutate_all line, the output is: a data frame with variable names "ideol 1", "ideol 2", "ideol 3".